# BeautifulSoup not finding tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a screen scraping project going. I have been using BeautiflSoup to pull out many items from the HTML. There is one item I cannot seem to get.

The item is in side of a form, of which there are multiple on the page. It's an input tag:

```
<input name="sqft" id="sqft" type="hidden" value="2,855"></input>
```

When I:

```
print soup
```

I can see in the result that the tag, as seen above, is in there. I dumped to a txt file and verified in my text editor that the full HTML is in the soup variable. From that, I have tried:

```
soup.find('input', {'name': 'sqft', 'id' : 'sqft', 'type' : 'hidden'})['value']
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have confirmed with a regex against the soup variable that the tag is there.

```
tmp = re.search('value=\"2,855\"', str(soup))

tmp.group(0)


Out[43]: 'value="2,855"'
```

I would like an elegant solution, and don't want to use a regex to pull the value.

I then tried:

```
tmp = soup.findAll('input')
```

Which inexplicably dumps a bunch of  tag types into tmp, but not the one I need. It's not missing only the one I need, but the one I need is missing.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
I have used the following code, and this works for now, but it seems *super* hacky

```
tmp = re.search('<input name=\"sqft\"(.*?)>', str(soup))

tmpsqfthtml = "<html>" + tmp.group(0) + "</input></html>"
sqft = BeautifulSoup(tmpsqfthtml).find('input')['value']
```

Comment: >>> b = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<input name="sqft" id="sqft" type="hidden" value="2,855"></input>')
>>> b.find('input')
<input id="sqft" name="sqft" type="hidden" value="2,855"/>
>>> b.find('input')['value']
'2,855'

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem as the value within the tag will vary, so I cannot do an exact regex against the tag. I could do a regex to extract the whole tag, but I have no guarantee that "id" and "type" are always in the same order.

Comment: @BrandonWatson I think comment from alkuzad means, He -and so do I- can't reproduce the problem using HTML snippet you posted. Reduced HTML markup that still produces the same problem would help us to investigate further

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
>>>soup.find('input', {'id': 'sqft'}).attrs['value']
'2,855'
```

#### How I find this method:

First, we find this tag by its id:

```
>>> input = soup.find('input', {'id': 'sqrt'})
```

when you don't know which method you can use, why not use `dir()`?

```
>>> dir(input)
....many methods here...
```

have a glance through all the methods, you may get some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at BeautifulSoup's documentation (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), there are a few things you can try:

1. `soup.input` should give you all the notes with `<input>` tags. Then you can do whatever you want to them
2. `soup.find_all("input")` instead of `soup.findAll("input")`
3. `soup.find("input", id="sqft")`

Alternatively, the problem might be that an `<input>` tag is not typically used with an opening and closing tag like you show above (`<input></input>`), but rather with the form `<input STUFF >`, so that could be causing a problem.

Comment: soup.input gives me a single input item, which I cannot iterate over. Using find_all("input") yields the result I highlight above, which is that I am getting a subset of the items I wish to receive, and the specific input tag I seek is not in the list.

Comment: You had a typo in `findAll` - I think that's from an old beautifulsoup API. What happens when you use the right `find_all` syntax?

Comment: mprat - see above. find_all does not give back all of the instances.

Comment: What about `soup.find("input", id="sqft")`?

Comment: Same issue - comes back as "None"

Comment: Is it possible that this tag is ephemeral?